# Как найти x в котором функция x ** 2 - 3(или любая другая функция) обнуляется (то есть при y = 0)

Tags: python, функции

Есть функция вида:

```
def func(x):

    return x ** 2 - 3
```

что по сути является `y = x^2 - 3`,

Вопрос, как найти **`x`** при **`y = 0`**, `func(0)` это при `x = 0` находим **`y`**, нужно обратное

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = x**2 - 3
y + 3 = x**2
x1 = (y + 3)**0.5
x2 = -(y + 3)**0.5
```

разве в школе не объясняли как решать уравнения?

После разъяснения понял задачу. Вам нужен метод Ньютона и ему подобные:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: функция меняется вручную, мне для каждого синуса, экспоненте и т.д. выражать x?

Comment: все, понял - почитайте про метод Ньютона (в вики есть примеры реализации на разных языках)

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Данная задача не особо является задачей по программированию, больше относится скорее к математике. Вспоминаем курс алгебры за 8 клас, и строим уравнение:

```
x²-3 = 0
x² = 3 #Это не код, а решение уравнения
x=+-√3
```

Однако, если вы под своим вопросом подразумевали, что функция будет разной,то это уже другой вопрос.

Если мы находимся в пределах квадратичной функции, полной или неполной, то нам нужно ее реализовывать слегка по другому:

```
def func(x, a, b, c): 
return a * x**2 + b * x +c #y=ax²+bx+c
```

И где то в программе хранить нужные a, b и c. Затем, когда нужно будет получить ноль функции (а именно так называется то, что мы ищем), мы решаем уравнение через дискриминант:

```
d=b*b - 4 * a * c #находим дискриминант
n = (-1*b+math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a) #первое значение
m = (-1*b-math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a) #второе значение
```

Итого мы имеем два числа, m и n, при которых функция ax²+bx+c будет равна 0.

Если же функция будет не квадратичной, а вообще произвольной, то не остаётся ничего, кроме как нарисовать график этой функции и найти нужную точку, однако это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: функция может быть любым нелинейным уравнением

Comment: Хорошо, насколько я вижу вам уже дали ответ на вопрос другие люди, более подходящий под условия. Просто ответ был дан пока я набирал текст, поэтому не видел